# How to write df to sheet while overwriting existing data?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I'm currently using Pandas to write a dataframe to a specific sheet, but it doesn't delete the 'old' data. It just writes on top of it.

This means if my dataframe is 5 rows, but the old data is 10 rows. Then I will overwrite the first 5 rows, but the old data remains in the remaining rows.

How can I modify this code to overwrite to the whole specified sheet?

I have data from a report feeding from the sheet, so I cannot delete rows or create a new sheet unfortunately.

```
book = load_workbook(workbookname)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(workbookname, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
df.to_excel(writer, "SheetName")

writer.save()
```

Comment: Do it directly in openpyxl.

Comment: Could you give me an example, please?